# sum number after _ per line awk

Tags: awk

I have a file which look like

```
09175b257668511_6428 e65a3ce76b9f5b4e_84 ec3cfe164cbd42ccd2ea7140_52
bf7ee04def3b0a_3 
135ada28a81dd82a77275f79d_3 447a424906a86edf2_2
```

I'm interested to sum up the numbers after the underscore on each line.

The number of items per line is differing. Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: Edit your question to show your expected output. Do you want totals per line , or the total across all lines? DO you want sub-totals? Do you want the original lines printed and then the totals? etc. etc.... Do not respond in comments - edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Some like this? It prints the total.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,a,"_");b+=a[2]}} END {print b}' file
6572
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[ _]' '{st=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) st+=$i; t+=st; print $0, st} END{print "TOTAL", t}' file
09175b257668511_6428 e65a3ce76b9f5b4e_84 ec3cfe164cbd42ccd2ea7140_52 6564
bf7ee04def3b0a_3  3
135ada28a81dd82a77275f79d_3 447a424906a86edf2_2 5
TOTAL 6572
```